# Enabling github pre commit hooks in origin for all collaborators

Tags: github

first: We use a github repository in the team for some projects. 
I'm using scripts defined in the pre-commit hook directory, locally (works perfect for my commits).

What I need is for every user (collaborator) to use the hooks without using symlinks or asking them to put them on their home folders.

Is there a way to set them up so the users can't commit if the scripts don't exit 0?.

Thanks.

Comment: You are probably looking for a [pre-receive](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.9/admin/guides/developer-workflow/creating-a-pre-receive-hook-script/) hook.

Comment: Thanks! That's more what I need from server side. I'll check it out how to adapt the script into that.

Answer (score 0):

As Henrik alluded to, in the Enterprise version, there is such a thing as the pre-receive hook.  It runs server side and so you would not need to install it on each collaborator's local machine.  But you are using github.com actual, and they don't allow pre receive hooks , nor do I expect they plan to; allowing indivduals to run scripts on their server isn't likely in their business plan. So that likely won't help you unless you are in a position to go to the enterprise product

There are some remedies you do have, however, but it won't be equivalent.  You can , for example, set a protected branch . You could thereby make it only you can check into that branch, and you of course would be using the local hook, every one else would be using a pull request.

Additionally, you could look into LGTM (Looks Good To Me) or similar automated pull request approval system.  I don't believe the official server is up but the source code is there and it could be run by someone else.  LGTM allows you to set a number of different conditions that would be closer to an equivalent to your pre-op hook.

Setting up such a system might well be more effort than it is worth to you, understandable; but it is do-able.

The main problem with using pre-commit hooks that come with git is that they  are local to your repos and don't get pushed to github.com.  I believe under the hood, those hooks aren't even transferred up to the repo on github, and that the pre-commit hook directory itself is not available like it is on the local copy of a git repo.

(I would say more on that architecture of the pre-commit hook dir except A. I am not sure if it is covered by NDA and B. I only saw the way it was on the Enterprise product, not github actual, and C. I don't know if the structure is still exactly the same)

Comment: Thanks! In my testing env I just use github, but where I need to finally use these hooks, we use enterprise. I don't have access to origin there, so I would have to adapt the scripts if needed and pass them to the team that manage github host and repos. The scripts are really simple, the main one that must exit 0 in a bash and uses 2 other scripts in python that checks json validation and other checks if the file is valid to sensu config.
I guess that I just need to ask them to put them under: $GIT_DIR/hooks/pre-receive
Like explained in here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack